how to generate embeddings in sagemaker?
based on an aws example, i have a code snippet for generating a vector from text data (sample code below). however, the sample doesn't provide a good explanation on use of mean pooling function below.
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer, DistilBertModel

model_name = "sentence-transformers/distilbert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens"


#Mean Pooling - Take attention mask into account for correct averaging
def mean_pooling(model_output, attention_mask):
    token_embeddings = model_output[0] #First element of model_output contains all token embeddings
    input_mask_expanded = attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1).expand(token_embeddings.size()).float()
    sum_embeddings = torch.sum(token_embeddings * input_mask_expanded, 1)
    sum_mask = torch.clamp(input_mask_expanded.sum(1), min=1e-9)
    return sum_embeddings / sum_mask


def sentence_to_vector(raw_inputs):
    tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
    model = DistilBertModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
    inputs_tokens = tokenizer(raw_inputs, padding=True, return_tensors="pt")
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(**inputs_tokens)

    sentence_embeddings = mean_pooling(outputs, inputs_tokens['attention_mask'])
    return sentence_embeddings


Are you facing any specific issue running this code on SageMaker? What is the ask here?
